# Complex mongodb data how to update

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

**I'm trying to update show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values.seat_status**
**this my code  .........................................................................................................................................................**
`db.seats.updateOne({'show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values._id':"62a9e044ec028e60180fe28a"},{$set:{'show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values.seat_status' : true}})`
.........................................................................................................................................................
please say what did i wrong**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd1dee"),
    "totalShowByDay" : "2",
    "totalShowDays" : 4,
    "movieId" : ObjectId("62953ba3cb6ae625ec9433e6"),
    "screenId" : ObjectId("6293b9638dde2d92658d5513"),
    "createdAt" : 1654930114438,
    "showId" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ed"),
    "show_seats" : [
        {
            "showByDate" : {
                "ShowDate" : "2022-06-11",
                "shows" : [
                    {
                        "showTime" : "2022-06-11T10:00",
                        "showSeats" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "category" : "CLASSIC",
                                    "seat_details" : [
                                        {
                                        "key" : "A",
                                        "values" : [
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ee"),
                                        "seat_number" : "1",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        },
,
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ef"),
                                        "seat_number" : "2",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14f0"),
                                        "seat_number" : "3",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00",,
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ef"),
                                        "seat_number" : "2",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14f0"),
                                        "seat_number" : "3",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        }
```

**this is what i ended up doing, I need best solution**

```
await db.getDb().collection(coll.seat).aggregate([
              {
                  '$unwind': {
                      'path': '$show_seats'
                  }
              }, {
                  '$unwind': {
                      'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows'
                  }
              }, {
                  '$unwind': {
                      'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats'
                  }
              }, {
                  '$unwind': {
                      'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats'
                  }
              }, {
                  '$unwind': {
                      'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details'
                  }
              }, {
                  '$unwind': {
                      'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values'
                  }
              }, {
                  '$match': {
                      'show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values._id': ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ee")

                  }
              }, {
                  $addFields: { "show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values.seat_status": true }
              }

          ])
```

Comment: There is no `$seat_status` property, there is only `seat_status`.

Comment: @Titus I try both but not working

Comment: Please revise and edit the document provided. It is not valid.

Comment: @YongShun did it!

Comment: Which value do you like to update? All of them or just a specific one?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit seat_status

Comment: Yes, which one? There are 5 seat_status in the document

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i want to change seat status matching _id document